# MySQL Workbench- Forward Engineer not adding new column to schema

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, database, mysql-workbench

When I create a new EER Diagram and use the `Forward Engineer` function it updates the localhost database and create the schema successfully.
However, if I then go back to the EER diagram and add a new column, save the model and then try `Forward Engineer` again, the new column is not added to the database. I've tried pressing the refresh button multiple times as well as disconnecting from the database and then re-connecting and it still doesn't show up.
The only way for me to add the new column using the EER diagram is to drop the schema, then run `Forward Engineer` to recreate the schema with the new column. Has anyone else experienced this, and if so what could the issue be?

Thanks

Comment: Exactly the same problem. I was about to type the very same thing -- and then found this. Ugh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer for me was to use "Synchronize Model" instead of "Forward Engineer" from the Database Menu